# How to retreive a column within double quotes in select SOQL

Tags: soql

I am getting data from SF via SOQL and then converting in into CSV. The problem is that I have a comments column which has multiple commas in the data so when I parse it out, each comment is breaking into multiple tabs.

If this was Oracle, I could concatenate "" [double quotes] to the comment field when I am retrieving it.

I could do something like this in Oracle:

```
Select id, concat(concat('"', comment),'"') from table1
```

Is there something similar in SOQL?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot manipulate the returned value in this way. If you want double quotes wrapping a field value, you'll need to add them yourself using post-processing.

If you are building this CSV via `Apex`, then it should pretty straightforward. For instance, you could add a helper method like:

```
public static String wrapDoubleQuotes(String input)
{
    return (input == null) ? '' : '"' + input + '"';
}
```